# How to return results from MySQL in HAPI

Tags: node.js, hapi

I'm new to Node and HAPI and am working through tutorials on a basic CRUD API.

I am trying to do a simple SQL query to retrieve a few rows out of the database and return the data in the request.

```
// routes.js
'use strict';
const Path = require('path');
const dbconn = require('./models');
const Home = require ('./controllers/home');

module.exports = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: Home,
        config: {
            description: 'Gets all the notes available'
        }
    },

];
```

---

```
// models.js
var db = require('mysql');

const db_name = 'nodejstest';
const db_user = 'nodejstest';
const db_pass = 'n0dejstest()';
const db_host = 'localhost';

var dbconn = db.createConnection({
    host: db_host,
    user: db_user,
    password: db_pass,
    database: db_name
});

dbconn.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('[mysql error]' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
});


module.exports = dbconn;
```

---

```
// home.js

'use strict';

const dbconn = require('../models');

function getAllNotes(callback) {
    dbconn.query('SELECT * FROM note', [], function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log(results);

        return callback(results);
    })
}

module.exports = async (request, h) => {
    return getAllNotes(function(results) {
        return {
            data: {
                notes: results
            },
            page: 'Home -- Notes Board',
            description: 'Welcome to my Notes Board'
        };

    })
    
}
```

In the console.log I am seeing the database results get logged correctly, so I know the db is returning what is expected but I cannot figure out how to get Hapi to wait until there are results from the db.

I'm on Node v12.18.1 & HAPI 19.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `async` function in `Home` is not returning the values from the callback. You are returning the result of calling `getAllNotes` which is undefined. You seem confused about how callbacks and async/promises work. You have to wrap the wrap the callback to the query in a Promise.

```js
function getAllNotes() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbconn.query('SELECT * FROM note', [], function (err, results) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(error)
      }

      console.log(results);

      return resolve(results);
    })
  })
}

module.exports = async (request, h) => {
  // maybe add some error handling here
  const results = await getAllNotes();
  return {
    data: {
      notes: results
    },
    page: 'Home -- Notes Board',
    description: 'Welcome to my Notes Board'
  };
}
```

Comment: thank you!  This worked perfectly and thank you for explaining why it wasn't working too :-)